# Creating data value for unique combinations of observations

Tags: r

I'm using R and interested in finding all of the unique combinations of products viewed within a visit.  Products are identified by product_key, visits by visit_key.  In the data below, visit_key = 1 views one product = pk_18280.  Visit_key = 28 is rows 2-4 and views three products (pk_57716, pk_1820, pk_14501).  The sequence the products is viewed in is unimportant for my analysis (and further, any ordering should result in the same grouping).

What I'd like is a column that could be used to find all visits that view only pk_18280 (like visit_key = 1) or that view all three products like visit_key = 28.

Thanks in advance!

```
    visitor_key visit_num product_key product_viewed orders visit_key
1         vid_1         1    pk_18280              1      0         1
2         vid_1         2    pk_57716              1      0        28
3         vid_1         2    pk_18280              1      1        28
4         vid_1         2    pk_14501              1      0        28
5         vid_1         3    pk_18280              1      0        37
6         vid_3         1    pk_18151              1      1         2
7         vid_3         1     pk_2467              1      0         2
8         vid_3         1      pk_967              1      0         2
9         vid_4         1   pk_138381              1      0         3
10        vid_4         1   pk_137338              1      0         3
11        vid_4         1   pk_137117              1      0         3
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of your question, call that data.frame `df`

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
Prod <- dt[,list("product_keys"=paste(product_key,collapse=",")),by=visit_key]
```

This produces a table of unique `visit_key` and pastes all the products viewed. A column that finds all `visit_key` for every group of `product_key` can be made by grouping on `Prod`

```
Key <- Prod[,list("visit_keys"=paste(visit_key,collapse=",")),by=product_keys]
```